# jQuery UI Datepicker does not change Value upon selecting a Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

All,

I've done a good bit of searching as this seems like a very common issue and moved things around in code a fair bit already, and nothing seems to be working.

Below is a simple snippet from a .aspx page we have. We are trying to quite simply select a date from the datepicker, and then actually have that date appear in the text box. Trouble is, regardless of what we default that date to (today, an arbitrary date, nothing at all, etc..), we can't get the date which is *selected* by the user to appear in this text box for our ClassificationStatusDate. The Datepicker seems to work, but upon inspecting things even in developer tools, nothing ever changes.

(this snippet is in its own  tag, separate from the second block which occurs later)

```
        <td class="editor-field">
            <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassificationStatusDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>            
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassificationStatusDate) %>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Later, we have the same snippet of code we've used elsewhere for all our script rendering:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptsSection" runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("input[id$='ClassificationStatusDate']").datepicker();
            });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

A couple things I've tried:

- Moving the scripts above everything else
- Changing the .datepicker() to be on a $('#ClassificationStatusDate')
  ID.
- Trying different default values
- A few other random odds and ends

This seems like a really fundamental problem, but maybe I'm just not binding something correctly, or something along those lines. I have heard of some individuals having to "wait for the DOM" to be ready, but I thought that's what I'm doing already with "$(function(){". But, perhaps there's something else off due to this being an app where its inputs are being constructed via Razor.

Comment: Javascript/Jquery interact with rendered HTML on the DOM so it might be better to post the rendered HTML. Your function call as you have here will wait for the DOM to render, but if there are still ajax calls that are loading data that your app and this field may depend on then you should consider if your binding might need to be done in some callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this today. Turns out, I had a HiddenFor up higher in my page as a small bug.

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClassificationStatusDate) %>
```

This caused the datepicker to be initialized for all items with the ID of "ClassificationStatusDate", but when it came to *changing* the value, it would only do it to the topmost element in the DOM. I removed this and all was fine. Maybe someone will learn from this!